# What is the most effective incapacitation?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

### Incapacitation ensures that the stealth-aspect of the game remains.

It makes it easier to capture outposts and completing missions since it makes sure that you're seen and heard as little as possible.

So, onto my question: **What are the means of incapacitation and which is the most and least effective ways?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### There are numerous ways to incapacitate your enemies.

Here's a full list, ranging from the option with the longest duration of incapacitation to the shortest.

- Full 5-hit CQC Combo (***Longest duration***)
- CQC Choke
- Tranquilizer Round
- CQC throw headfirst into a wall
- CQC throw on the ground (***Shortest duration***)

**Bonus:** Holding up an enemy at gunpoint and asking them to lie down will make them incapacitated indefinitely up until another enemy notices them.

*However*, if the base goes on full combat alert then they will get up.

Comment: Where does forcing someone to the ground after a holdup rank?

Comment: That would be the "CQC throw on the ground", if you're referring to when you throw on the ground so that they get stunned.

Comment: Actually, holding someone up is different from CQC throwing. Instead of grabbing or hitting an enemy, you need to aim at him while very close. It's not a very well known technique, since most people never bother with pulling their gun out at such short distances.

Comment: I didn't say that CQC throwing was the same thing as holding up an enemy. The question was what "forcing someone to the ground after a holdup" would rank as.

Comment: I'm referring to when you hold someone up, then hit L1 and tell them to go to the ground. They'll lie down on their stomach and a --- marker will appear over their heads, as opposed to a ZZZ or STN marker.

Comment: Oh, well that duration is indefinete. They will remain until another enemy finds them.

Comment: Thank you for adding that information. I'd never noticed them get out of that situation but I hadn't tested it myself. +1!

Comment: Yeah no problem, I didn't really know where to put it on the list, because depending on the circumstances it could either be the shortest or the longest duration. Added it nonetheless.

Comment: I *believe*, if the enemy doesn't notice you, you only need to do a 3-hit CQC combo. Not sure how to verify, but I've never been able to do the full 5 from stealth. (And you get the action cam on the 3rd hit too)

Comment: Do you mean that a 3-hit CQC combo would incapacitate the target as long as a 5-hit CQC combo?

Comment: There is also, dropping them from a height, rubber bullet weapons, hitting them with a jeep, stun nade, sleep nade, air support sleep gas, sleep gas mine, stun arm, DD stun, stun decoy. I think all the sleep weapons are the most effective, and all the stun stuff is as effective as the CQC choke

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the majority of these are variations of the ones listed above.

Comment: Note: an enemy forced to the ground after a hold-up will get up if the base goes on full combat alert (i.e. someone saw you).

Comment: Great catch. Updating.

Comment: @P1raten No, I mean, I think the CQC combo from stealth is different from the CQC combo not-in-stealth.

Comment: @RavenDreamer That could be true. I have seen Snake perform combos ranging from 3 to 5 hits, with no apparent reason as to why. Maybe it's a timing thing that I'm not paying close enough attention to? At any rate, as long as you get the final hit to the jaw (the comical afterburner sound effect plays and time slows) it seems like you get the full duration.

Comment: Do you know how long these last in in-game hours? I'll tack a 250 point bounty on if you gather that info.

Comment: Also if you speed up the choke by repeatedly pressing the button, the stun lasts less time

Answer (score 2):

To extend Linus Juhlin's answer, here are some of my observations:

- Knocking an enemy down by throwing them (or kicking while they are on the ground or riding them over with D-Horse/D-walker) incapacitates for a lesser period of time than choking them.
- If another guard finds knocked out guard, he rises an alarm. If another guard finds a sleeping guard, he just wakes him up (no alarm). If another guard finds a sleeping guard lying on the bed, he leaves him alone.
- Knocked out/sleeping guards will NEVER come to (unless they are found by other guards), if you put them inside a portable toilet/garbage bin/passenger seat of jeep or truck/in the back of the track (you can load a whole base worth of guards in the back of the track - they will never wake up on their own!).
- There is 6th ways to incapacitate your enemies - crawl to 15m or closer to the guard(s), open iDroid, go to music menu, turn on loudspeaker and play "afganian lullaby". If guard stays within 15m from you until the song ends, he will go to sleep. However, for some reason I've lost this tape after the first use (not sure if it's a bug or if this tape is one use only)

Comment: There are two tapes that put enemies to sleep when played on the speaker: “Afghan Lullaby” and “African Lullaby”. They do indeed destroy themselves after you use them once to put enemies to sleep. To get the tapes back, you must return to where you originally found them and pick them up again.