# How long do stunned soldiers stay unconscious?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

I know there are multiple ways to render a target unconscious -- CQC, tranq dart, sleep grenade, chokehold, etc. It's just that right now I'm dealing with kind of a large outpost and I don't think I have the time to sneak out and wait for a Fulton resupply.

On the other hand, I don't want a guard to wake up and call the alarm just when I don't need it, especially since I've already interrogated them.

So how long does an enemy stay out after you've hugged them to sleep? I *do* know they can wake up out of a tranq dart annoyingly early if you get distracted...

Comment: I wouldn't mind seeing durations for all KO methods... If I know I'll be at an outpost for any extended period of time, I usually just kill soldiers in the early parts so I don't run into this problem.

Comment: This is actually detailed in an earlier question. Let me see if I can find it. EDIT: Here we go: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/235548/what-is-the-most-effective-incapacitation They are ranked from longest to shortest, which is helpful, but nothing about exact duration if you're looking for that.

Comment: `I don't think I have the time to sneak out and wait for a Fulton resupply.` - you don't need to sneak out. Just call in a resupply right on top of yourself. No one will notice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I do know they can wake up out of a tranq dart annoyingly early if you get distracted...

Tranq darts are actually quite effective if the guards remain undisturbed. The trouble with tranq darts is that patrolling guards will wake up sleeping (**ZZZ** marker) guards if they're noticed, so you have to be sure to hide sleeping guards somewhere out of patrol route. This doesn't raise alert level because the sleeping guy's comrade assumes that he was just lazy.

Unconscious (**STN** marker) cannot be woken by a simple tap and will cause other guards to become suspicious if the knocked-out one is noticed. So it is a tradeoff -- you can either use tranq darts and be safe from raising the alert level of the base, even if the sleeping guy is noticed, or you can knock them out and be sure that the guard won't wake up, but if he's noticed the base will go up in alert level.

> So how long does an enemy stay out after you've hugged them to sleep?

Unfortunately I can't give you a precise estimate. From my experience, I can tell you that it is *roughly* as long, maybe a little longer, than an undisturbed tranq dart. I think that it is around 6-8 in-game hours. CQC throws are very short term, lasting maybe 10 real-time seconds. Headfirst throws into walls last longer, but not that much. If you have to do a chain-throw to a group of guards, it is best to either shoot them with a tranq dart afterwards, or wake them up again and choke them out, to ensure they don't wake up shortly.

Comment: There's an annoying bug, where if you slam them (which is a short stun duration) and then tranq them while they're on the ground they'll wake up after the STN wears, instead of the length of the tranq which you'd expect.

Comment: There's a minor bug I found where you can put incapacitated enemies into a vehicle (I've tested this with jeeps in Afghanistan free-roam), and they will *never* wake up unless another enemy disturbs them, or you take them out of the vehicle.  I used this method to drive a single unconscious guard all over the map as my unwitting sidekick (Quiet was super jealous because she had to walk).